# Why don't jQuery File Upload plugin's process events trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, process, jquery-file-upload

I have a weird problem with jQuery File Upload plugin.
If I use this sitax:

```
$('fileupload').fileupload({
  url: myurl,
  add: function(e, data){
    console.log("add event");
  },
  processalways: function(e, data){
    console.log("processalways event");
  }
});
```

processalways event don't occur, but I got correct *data.context* variable (i.e. the div with the progress bar of the added file).

While when I use this sintax

```
$('fileupload').fileupload({
  url: myurl
}).on('fileuploadadd',function(e, data){
    console.log("add event");
}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function(e, data){
    console.log("processalways event");
});
```

processalways event correctly occur, but I got wrong *data.context* (I think in this case data.context will always refer to *$('fileupload')* element.

I need both process event and *data.context* variable. How can I do?

Comment: Hi Thiezar! I have the same situation and from what I understand if you reimplement the add callback, you will need to somehow trigger the process like in docs example (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#add). However, when I do that like in the example it the processalways events still does not get triggered. If I stick to the default add implementation it DOES get fired. Wondering whether you figure this one out?

Comment: Oh I figured it out for my case at least: if you re-implement the add callback you should do it as a bind and not as an option (like the author recommends), so it wont override the options for additional resources. So use something like: $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {/* ... */})

Comment: I tried to implement it as a bind too but for some other reasons something else went wrong. So I solved the problem by dropping out jQuery File Upload plugin and using Plupload plugin. With Plupload I was able to do everything as I wanted in no time.

Comment: Joni's suggestion also fixed my problem. Use on('fileuploadadd') instead of the 'add:' option.

Comment: I added on('fileuploadadd'), and on("fileuploadprocessalways") but processalways still doesnt fire as I expected :/

Comment: Ahh, I figured out the problem. I forgot to reference the **fileupload-proccess.js**   and **fileupload.image.js** to page.

Comment: @Thiezar, have you found the solution please help me

Answer (score 3):

## First syntax

If you want to start the process you have to call `data.submit();` into the add fnction.

Then you can't call a `processalways` callback, [according to the documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#always) it's `always` which should be used :

```
$('input').fileupload({
    url: "/echo/json",
    add: function (e, data) {
        console.log("Add callback");
        $('#start_upload').click(function(){
            data.submit();
        });
    },
    always: function (e, data) {
        console.log("Always callback");
    }
});
```

## Second syntax

I've never use it, but if it works it's because `fileuploadd` doesn't exist. And so it's the default `fileuploadadd` which is used, and it may call `data.submit()`.

Comment: Sorry I wrote the wrong name for *fileuploadadd*.
I do use *data.submit()* in the add event. I didn't write in the example just for simplicity.
According to the documentation, there is an *always* event AND a *processalways* event. But all process events (i.e. *process*, *processstart*, *processalways*, etc.) don't trigger.

Comment: I've edited my answer 'couse I realized I actually use *data.submit()* in my add callback XD

Comment: @Thiezar : You're right, there is a _processalways_ event, I never used it. I don't understand yet the difference between _processalways_ and _always_ but I've read somewhere that the equivalent of the Ajax _complete_ event is the [tag:jquery-file-upload]'s _always_ one's. But it may depend of what you want to do.

Comment: Process events just occur during the processing of the file you choose. For example in case of images during process a preview image is generated, resized and cropped.
While always event is just calld for completed ajax request.
I use *processalways* to load a preview image next to the choosen file name.

Answer (score 0):

I had read a bit code in [jquery.fileupload-ui.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js)

Maybe this is what you want?

```html
// The add callback is invoked as soon as files are added to the fileupload
// widget (via file input selection, drag & drop or add API call).
// See the basic file upload widget for more information:
add: function (e, data) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        return false;
    }
    var $this = $(this),
        that = $this.data('blueimp-fileupload') ||
            $this.data('fileupload'),
        options = that.options;
    data.context = that._renderUpload(data.files)
        .data('data', data)
        .addClass('processing');
    options.filesContainer[
        options.prependFiles ? 'prepend' : 'append'
        ](data.context);
    that._forceReflow(data.context);
    that._transition(data.context);
    data.process(function () {
        return $this.fileupload('process', data);
    }).always(function () {
        data.context.each(function (index) {
            $(this).find('.size').text(
                that._formatFileSize(data.files[index].size)
            );
        }).removeClass('processing');
        that._renderPreviews(data);
    }).done(function () {
        data.context.find('.start').prop('disabled', false);
        if ((that._trigger('added', e, data) !== false) &&
            (options.autoUpload || data.autoUpload) &&
            data.autoUpload !== false) {
            data.submit();
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        if (data.files.error) {
            data.context.each(function (index) {
                var error = data.files[index].error;
                if (error) {
                    $(this).find('.error').text(error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```